# Decrypt password in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, magento

How to decrypt password in plain text which are in ms-SQL database?

```
$encrypted_password="k??aU?????y-??N???tDRz????{?4R???G?aS4t?T";  
$salt = "611233880";
```

So I need to decrypt password so that I insert into other database with md5 encryption.

I  used this code, but not get success

```
$iv2 = '';
 for($i=0;$i<16;$i++){
    $iv2 .= "\0";
 }
 $plain_text_CBC = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $salt, $encrypted_password, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv2);
 var_dump($plain_text_CBC);
 $plaintext = openssl_decrypt($encrypted_password, 'AES-256-CBC', $salt, 0, $iv2);
 var_dump($plaintext);
```

Need Help

Comment: `md5()` is not an encryption.. but a hashing algorithm -_-

Comment: You cannot decrypt old password. You should encrypt data you wrote into password field and compare result with data in database. If they are equal, you will pass password check.

Comment: so what can i do for getting solution?

Comment: I suggest first to find out how passwords are actually stored in MS-SQL. Most likely they are stored hashed, not encrypted. Consult the documentation for this.

Comment: Password are same in database like this "k??aU?????y-??N???tDRz????{?4R???G?aS4t?T"..

Answer (score 2):

The idea behind encrypted (or hashed) passwords is that it is a one way operation. Not quite like shredding, but that's the idea. If you take exactly the same input and shred it you should get exactly the same output. You may not be able to reconstruct the input from it, but you can confirm someone gave you the right input by looking at the output.

Some weak algorithms have been know to be hacked buy in principle what you are asking for is impossible.

The ought to be no reason reason to decrypt. You can always do the hashing operation twice - first with the old algorithm, then with the new one - and then compare with the entry in the database.

NEVER EVER store plaintext (or weakly encrypted) passwords. Just ask LinkedIn...

Comment: what with "just ask linkedin" ?

Comment: @mrcoder - see http://www.zdnet.com/blog/ou/putting-the-cracking-of-sha-1-in-perspective/409 and http://www.zdnet.com/blog/btl/6-46-million-linkedin-passwords-leaked-online/79290 for an idea of what I was talking about.

Answer (score 2):

You don't simply decrypt a password. It should be hashed which means it is a one way encryption.

If you want to change your password hashing implementation, here is a way to do it.

You have the clear text password available when a user is in the process of logging in. So that's where you will have to place code to rehash the password with the new algorithm.

If you are using the new native [password hashing functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.password.php) (PHP Version >= 5.5) then you can use [password_needs_rehash](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-needs-rehash.php). If you are on a lower PHP Version but still >= 5.3.7 then you can use the [userland implementation](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) to get the same API to the password hashing functions.

So when a user is attempting to log in and the password needs rehashing, check if the hashes match with the old hashing function and then create and save the new one to the database. Over time you will be able to migrate most users and then you can think about a solution to migrate the rest of your userbase with a forced password reset if they never logged in during your migration timeframe.

Comment: Good links to the various password hashing options

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you encrypting your data by 2 different algorithms. Why? One algorithm is enough.

Answer: You can't decrypt old password.

Solution: You should encrypt data you wrote into password field and compare result with data in database. If they are equal, you will pass password check.

For example:

```
$login = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['login']);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
$password_hash = md5($input); // you can use there any other algorithm, just example

// make next query and control result
$sql = 'select count(id) from users where login = \'$login\' and password = \'$password_hash\'';

// now if there are 1 row with this login and same password hash let user log in to your site
```

Comment: md5 should never be used for passwords

Comment: this encrypt password is in ms-sql and i am importing customer data into mysql so i didn't have a solution to decrypt a password .

Comment: md5 should not be used for passwords at all. You can use md5 in php too to check the passwords in PHP as laid out in my solution. Password hashing belongs into the application code and not into the database.

Comment: It is just example, you can use any other algorithm.

Answer (score -1):

If you write your code in the MVC structure, you can use the function n_decrypt() to decrypt passwords.

Comment: what does using a function has to do with using a design pattern? functions are avalible to a language; not dependent on a drawing/scheme somewhere...